# Authorization for showcasing customer project as portifolio

Tags: portfolio

You guys get used to ask for your customers for posting finished customer projects on your site as *portifolio*?

Do you do it directly without asking for some *formal authorization* via e-mail or the like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to have a term in your contract that says you can use the work in your portfolio. You don't need to explicitly mention it separately from that. But don't try to hide this term either. It should be prominently mentioned. If a client doesn't want that you can remove it from the terms on a per project basis.

No, I don't ask formally. If you forgot to ask previous clients then you would need to go back to them and formally ask. That could be in email.